# Android 7.1.1 takes 4gb of space on Nexus 5x

Tags: internal-storage, 7.0-nougat, nexus-5x

I have recently updated my Nexus 5x to Android 7.1.1 and noticed that now operating system takes 4gb of my internal storage. These 4gb are a bit critical to me as I have 16gb model.

I have found one post on [AndroidCentral](http://forums.androidcentral.com/nexus-5x/752371-nexus-5x-nougat-7-1-1-update-memory-hog.html) what relates to my issue, but it is not clear if the issue got solved or not.

I have two questions:

1. How can I restore the 4gb taken by the new system update?
2. Is it possible to restore this space without factory resetting the phone?